# How to catch KeyError in a python for loop with lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to catch a `KeyError` for `x['uri']` for this particular scenario.

```
joined_rooms = ('coala/coala', 'coala/coala-bears')
room_data = [{'id': '130', 'uri': 'coala/coala'},
             {'id': '234', 'name': 'Nitanshu'},
             {'id': '897', 'uri': 'coala/coala-bears'}]

for room in filter(lambda x: x['uri'] in joined_rooms, room_data):
    #do stuff
```

Doing this:

```
try:
    for room in filter(lambda x: x['uri'] in joined_rooms, room_data):
        #do stuff
except KeyError:
    pass
```

will skip all the items after `KeyError` is raised.

Is there any way to handle this apart from migrating to the classic nested `for loops` with `if condition`?

Comment: Not if you write it that way in a `filter(..)`, since the filter will not catch the exception, but you can inline the "filtering".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python `dict`s have a `get` method for just such an occasion. It takes two arguments, first is the key you're looking for, second is the default value to use if the key is not present in the dictionary. Try this:

```
for room in filter(lambda x:x.get('uri',None) in joined_rooms, room_data):
    #do stuff
```

The problem here, although it might not be a problem in your case, is that you're left with needing to supply a default value that will *never* appear in `joined_rooms`.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot for this. It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can use `dict.get` to return a default value if a key does not exist in a dictionary. If not provided, this default value is `None`.

As an alternative, you can use a generator expression. This will be more efficient than `filter` + `lambda` expression. It may also be more readable:

```
for room in (x for x in room_data if x.get('iri') in joined_rooms):
    # do something
```

Another perfectly valid solution is to use an `if` statement within your `for` loop:

```
for room in room_data:
    if 'iri' in room:
        # do something
```